# "'2008' is not a valid warning number" warning upon launch

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, warnings

Right, I keep getting this **warning** message every time I create a new project in **Visual Studio 2010**.

All it says is `'2008' is not a valid warning number`.

As it is more of a warning than an error, it hasn't caused any harm so far, but I don't know what caused it or how to get rid of it.

I havent installed/uninstalled any new programs - as I looked around I noticed people going from **Visual Studio 2011** to **Visual Studio 2010** - which is not the case here.

To be honest, first Visual Studio wouldn't let me create a project, but would throw me an error message. What it said have I forgotten. When I restarted it, it worked in regards to creating a project - but keeps creating this warning. Even if I restart Visual Studio.

So in general, all of you who will *still* ask: ***I HAVE NOT DONE ANYTHING WITH MY COMPUTER, THAT WOULD CREATE THIS WARNING MESSAGE.***

And no, this warning will not go away.

Any ideas?
Cheers.

Comment: Search for `@pragma` in your solution, and see if `@pragma warning 2008` is there

Comment: It may also be due to a bug reported [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/694800/error-cs1691-warning-as-error-2008-is-not-a-valid-warning-number)

Comment: Interesting, but unfortunately my solution does not contain `@pragma`. This warning seems to be popular within Visual Studio 11. Visual Studio 10 is the case here. Perhaps re-booting the computer is an option?

Comment: @Habib, the problem occurs when creating a new project, so `@pragma` isn't in the solution.

Comment: After getting VS 2012, VS 2010 Express now has that warning too. Don't worry about it at all